# iOS countdown, app badge number, and save the time left

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need some help looking to create a icon badge number for days left
and I need help saving the time left when you close the app, so it keeps counting.

I tried looking online, but I am not to savvy enough yet to know where all the code goes.

The countdown works fine if I stay in the app.

.h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

   @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *startCountdown;
   @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
   @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *countdownLabel;
   - (IBAction)startCountdown:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m file

```
- (IBAction)startCountdown:(id)sender {
    //Remove the time component from the datePicker.  We care only about the date
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
    NSUInteger preservedComponents = (NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay);
    self.datePicker.date = [calendar dateFromComponents:[calendar components:preservedComponents fromDate:self.datePicker.date]];

    //Set up a timer that calls the updateTime method every second to update the label
    NSTimer *timer;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(updateTime)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
}

-(void)updateTime
{
    //Get the time left until the specified date
    NSInteger ti = ((NSInteger)[self.datePicker.date timeIntervalSinceNow]);
    NSInteger seconds = ti % 60;
    NSInteger minutes = (ti / 60) % 60;
    NSInteger hours = (ti / 3600) % 24;
    NSInteger days = (ti / 86400);

    //Update the label with the remaining time
    self.countdownLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02li days %02li hrs %02li min %02li sec", (long)days, (long)hours, (long)minutes, (long)seconds];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: `[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;`

Comment: again, i apologize for my lack of knowledge. Where does that line of code go and how do i make it pull from the nsinteger for days left?

Comment: The code will set the badge number to 1 anywhere in your code. To change the badge in background, it's better to do it through local notifications.

Comment: ok i will look into that, any tips on how i save the date on app exit? right now you open the app set the date , hit start countdown. it works. close the app and it resets the clock and date picker

Comment: You need to look into different persistence storage options, e.g. plist, core data, NSUserDefaults. Then whenever you exit the app, corresponding delegate method will be called in AppDelegate file. Also in `viewDidLoad`, load the stored value rather than setting it as constant.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder where you save the value of your datePicker. As I read your code you presented in this question all values will be discarded after I close the app. Somewhere in your app you should save the updated time left. As I read your code you fire up a timer that measures the time difference between the datePickers's time and the time the timer fires up.

You can build a class that holds the remaining time and make that class conform to the NSCoding protocol. Then you implement the methods encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder for saving your remaining time class and implement initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder to load your remaining time.

In the view controller you call, for instance, in viewDidLoad [NSKEyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:(NSString *)path] to load your save remaining time. When the app closes you call [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject: yourTimer toFile:path]

Then your timer will resume counting correctly.

Comment: what do i put in for "yourtimer" ... do i put in the ui label? seems that is the only step i have left to figure out

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to explain that. The object your timer is the remaining time you want to save or the time stamp that the countdown started. As I understood your code, you take a timestamp when the countdown starts and you measure the time left comparing the timestamp with the timeIntervalSinceNow. You either save the time stamp when you start the countdown and use this, or you save the time left and start from there when the app starts again.

Comment: how do i save the time stamp? can you assist with a little coding.

Comment: Hi Justin, I can make an example in Swift, but it has been a while since I've programmeer in Objective-C and since I'm programming in Swift, I don't like to go back. It takes me forever to het something up and running in Objective-C. so, if you can settel for a Swift example, I can give you some code.

Comment: Hi Justin, you can find the code in the following link https://github.com/MacUserT/CountDown.